# Angular 10: Bundle creation for lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, bundle, ivy, angular10

I have a service which uses xslx library to create a excel report. Since xlsx is pretty big and its only used in one place I want to put the service and also the dependency into a lazy loaded module.

So far everything works fine: I lazy load the module where I need it and then get the service from the modules injector. Issue is now to get an instance of my service I need to import it into the component where I use it. And as soon as I do this the xlsx gets bundled into the module where I use the service and not into the lazy loaded one.

Any Ideas?

Thx
Markus